# How to test ViewModel if flow from RemoteMediator (paging 3) library has been collected or implemented in this?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, junit

I am getting this exception while unit testing the viewModel.

```
Exception in thread "UI thread @coroutine#1" java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method androidx.paging.CachedPagingDataKt.cachedIn, parameter <this>
    at androidx.paging.CachedPagingDataKt.cachedIn(CachedPagingData.kt)
    at com.sarmad.newsprism.news.ui.NewsViewModel$getNewsStream$1.invokeSuspend(NewsViewModel.kt:46)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [CoroutineId(1), "coroutine#1":StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@67526363, Dispatchers.Main]

expected:<false> but was:<true>
Expected :false
Actual   :true
```

I want to test if `newsViewModel.getNewsStream()` is called, it should start loading, stop loading and expose updated UiState to NewsFragment so fragment can call adapter.submitData(data). But, there is an exception indication an error (I am a beginner and I can't understand that even after research for a good amount of time) in `cachedIn(viewModelScope)` operator while I am collecting flow in viewModel.

**NewsViewModel**

```
package com.sarmad.newsprism.news.ui

@HiltViewModel
class NewsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val newsRepository: NewsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        const val KEY_SUBREDDIT = "us"
        const val DEFAULT_SUBREDDIT = "androiddev"
    }

    init {
        if (!savedStateHandle.contains(KEY_SUBREDDIT)) {
            savedStateHandle[KEY_SUBREDDIT] = DEFAULT_SUBREDDIT
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val articles = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>(KEY_SUBREDDIT)
        .asFlow()
        .flatMapLatest {
            newsRepository.getBreakingNewsStream(it)
        }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    private val _userMessage = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    private val _newsArticles = articles

    val uiState: StateFlow<NewsItemListUiState> = combine(
        _isLoading, _userMessage, _newsArticles
    ) { isLoading, userMessage, newsArticles ->
        NewsItemListUiState(
            news = newsArticles,
            isLoading = isLoading,
            userMessage = userMessage
        )
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L),
        initialValue = NewsItemListUiState(isLoading = true)
    )

    fun refresh() {
        _isLoading.value = true
        viewModelScope.launch {
            newsRepository.refreshTasks()
            _isLoading.value = false
        }
    }
}
```

**NewsRepository**

```
package com.sarmad.newsprism.data.repository

import androidx.paging.PagingData
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.entities.NewsResponse
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.Result
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.entities.Article

interface NewsRepository {


    suspend fun getSearchedNewsStream(searchQuery: String, pageNumber: Int):
            Flow<NewsResponse>

    suspend fun getBreakingNewsStream(countryCode: String): Flow<PagingData<Article>>
}
```

**NewsRepositoryImpl**

```
package com.sarmad.newsprism.data.repository

import android.util.Log
import androidx.paging.*
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.Result
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.entities.Article
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.entities.NewsResponse
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.localdatasource.ArticleDao
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.localdatasource.ArticleDatabase
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.localdatasource.RemoteKeysDao
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.paging.mediaters.NewsRemoteMediator
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.remotedatasource.api.NewsApi
import com.sarmad.newsprism.utils.Constants.Companion.PAGING_CONFIG_PAGE_SIZE
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.emptyFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.mapLatest
import javax.inject.Inject

private const val TAG = "NewsRepositoryImpl"

class NewsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val api: NewsApi,
    private val articleDao: ArticleDao,
    private val articleDatabase: ArticleDatabase,
    private val remoteKeysDao: RemoteKeysDao,
) : NewsRepository {

    override suspend fun getSearchedNewsStream(
        searchQuery: String,
        pageNumber: Int
    ): Flow<NewsResponse> = flow {
        val searchedNewsResponse = api.searchNews(searchQuery, pageNumber)

        if (searchedNewsResponse.isSuccessful) searchedNewsResponse.body()
            ?.let { newsList -> emit(newsList) }
        else emptyFlow<NewsResponse>()
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    override suspend fun getBreakingNewsStream(
        countryCode: String
    ): Flow<PagingData<Article>> {

     return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = PAGING_CONFIG_PAGE_SIZE
            ),
            remoteMediator = NewsRemoteMediator(articleDatabase, articleDao, remoteKeysDao, api),
            pagingSourceFactory = { articleDao.getNewsStream() }
        ).flow
    }
}
```

**NewsRemoteMadiator**

```
package com.sarmad.newsprism.data.paging.mediaters

import androidx.paging.ExperimentalPagingApi
import androidx.paging.LoadType
import androidx.paging.PagingState
import androidx.paging.RemoteMediator
import androidx.room.withTransaction
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.remotedatasource.api.NewsApi
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.entities.Article
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.entities.ArticleRemoteKey
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.localdatasource.ArticleDao
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.localdatasource.ArticleDatabase
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.localdatasource.RemoteKeysDao
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlin.math.ceil

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class NewsRemoteMediator @Inject constructor(
    private val articleDatabase: ArticleDatabase,
    private val articleDao: ArticleDao,
    private val remoteKeysDao: RemoteKeysDao,
    private val api: NewsApi
) : RemoteMediator<Int, Article>() {

    override suspend fun initialize(): InitializeAction {
        val newsCacheTimeout = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        val isSkipRefresh = remoteKeysDao.getLastUpdateTime()?.let {
            System.currentTimeMillis() - it >= newsCacheTimeout
        }

        return if (isSkipRefresh == true) {
            InitializeAction.SKIP_INITIAL_REFRESH
        } else {
            InitializeAction.LAUNCH_INITIAL_REFRESH
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, Article>
    ): MediatorResult {
        return try {

            val currentPage = when (loadType) {
                LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                    val remoteKey = getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(state)
                    remoteKey?.nextPage?.minus(1) ?: 1
                }
                LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                    val remoteKey = getRemoteKeyForFirstItem(state)
                    val prevPage = remoteKey?.prevPage ?: return MediatorResult.Success(
                        remoteKey != null
                    )
                    prevPage
                }
                LoadType.APPEND -> {
                    val remoteKey = getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state)
                    val nextPage =
                        remoteKey?.nextPage
                            ?: return MediatorResult.Success(remoteKey != null)
                    nextPage
                }
            }

            val response = api.getBreakingNews("us", currentPage)

            val totalPages = response.body()?.totalResults?.toDouble()?.div(20)?.let { pages ->
                ceil(pages)
            }?.toInt()

            val endOfPaginationReached = totalPages == currentPage

            val nextPage = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else currentPage.plus(1)
            val prevPage = if (currentPage == 1) null else currentPage.minus(1)

            articleDatabase.withTransaction {

                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    articleDao.deleteAllArticles()
                    remoteKeysDao.deleteAllArticleRemoteKeys()
                }

                response.body()?.let { response ->
                    val keys = articleDao.insertAll(response.articles)

                    val mappedKeysToArticles = keys.map { key ->
                        ArticleRemoteKey(
                            id = key.toInt(),
                            nextPage = nextPage,
                            prevPage = prevPage,
                            modifiedAt = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        )
                    }
                    remoteKeysDao.insertArticleRemoteKeys(mappedKeysToArticles)
                }
            }
            MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached)
        } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(
        state: PagingState<Int, Article>
    ): ArticleRemoteKey? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { pos ->
            state.closestItemToPosition(pos)?.id?.let { id ->
                remoteKeysDao.getArticleRemoteKey(id)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForFirstItem(
        state: PagingState<Int, Article>
    ): ArticleRemoteKey? {

        return state.pages.firstOrNull {
            it.data.isNotEmpty()
        }?.data?.firstOrNull().let {
            it?.let { it1 -> remoteKeysDao.getArticleRemoteKey(it1.id) }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForLastItem(
        state: PagingState<Int, Article>
    ): ArticleRemoteKey? {

        return state.pages.lastOrNull {
            it.data.isNotEmpty()
        }?.data?.lastOrNull().let {
            it?.let { it1 -> remoteKeysDao.getArticleRemoteKey(it1.id) }
        }
    }
}
```

**NewsViewModelTest**

```
package com.sarmad.newsprism.news.ui

import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.remotedatasource.api.NewsApi
import com.sarmad.newsprism.data.repository.NewsRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.DelicateCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.newSingleThreadContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.advanceUntilIdle
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

internal class NewsViewModelTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var newsRepository: NewsRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var newsApi: NewsApi

    private lateinit var newsViewModel: NewsViewModel

    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)
        newsViewModel = NewsViewModel(newsRepository)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // reset the main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun test_getNewsFlow() = runTest {

        newsViewModel.getNewsStream("us")
        assertEquals(true, newsViewModel.newsFlow.value.isLoading)

        advanceUntilIdle()

        assertEquals(
            false,
            newsViewModel.newsFlow.value.isLoading
        )

        assertNotNull(
            newsViewModel.newsFlow.value.news
        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check a call is using a Mock.

Create an interface for your NewsViewModel like INewsViewModel and inject it by using the constructor or the Setup. Depending on your Mock package it can be created like:

```
//Implementation using Moq     
Mock<INewsViewModel> mock = new Mock<INewsViewModel>(); 
mock.Setup(m => m.getNewsStream());
// Your test 
mock.VerifyAll();
```

Moq also allows to create a Mock when the mocked class has an empty constructor.